# Discord api grant type None is not supported

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord

this code returns me this: {"error": "unsupported_grant_type", "error_description": "Grant type None is not supported"}. What am i doing wrong?

```
app.get('*', (req,res) => {
res.sendFile(__dirname + "/test.html")
console.log(req.query.code)
const Body = {
    client_id: "870076989682360330",
    client_secret: "my secret",
    code: req.query.code,
    redirect_uri: "http://localhost:3000",
    grant_type: "authorization_code",
    scope :"scope"
}
if(req.query.code) {

    reqst.post({
        uri: "https://discord.com/api/oauth2/token",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        body: JSON.stringify(Body)
    }, (x,y,z) => {
        console.log(z)
    })

}
```

})

Comment: I'm not an expert on node, but I found [this documentation](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant). I wonder if it might help you

Comment: I just copied code from there and ported it to node, but it doesnt work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Ouath2 Access Token 'Grant type None is not supported'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67365624/discord-ouath2-access-token-grant-type-none-is-not-supported)

Answer (score 0):

Do you have scopes? if not try adding scopes and if yes you can check this [Discord Ouath2 Access Token 'Grant type None is not supported'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67365624/discord-ouath2-access-token-grant-type-none-is-not-supported) and discord docs https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#authorization-code-grant

Comment: Docs say that scopes arent required in getting data about user, and yes, i have scope identify when logging in